# Android Lollipop :Task process and intent flags

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 apps let's say A and B. **App A** has activity **x** and **app B** has activity **1,2**. In app B activity 1 is launcher activity with no flags and activity 2 is singleTask also Activity 1 starts activity 2(for result) with no flags. In app A there is a button in activity x which starts app B's activity 1 with new_task_flag.

My question is when I tap on button then I have 2 tasks i.e **x** and **1->2**, on pressing hardware home button and launching app B then what will be the behaviour of these task. From my understanding task **1->2** should come in foreground but I see multiple instances of activity 2 stacked on task. What am I missing here ?

I have gone through several stackoverflow posts like [Android task and process, SingleTask and SingleInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611543/android-task-and-process-singletask-and-singleinstance) (David's elaborate answer) and google docs but unable to figure out problem here.

Comment: A few problems: #1 Activity1 cannot start Activity2 (for result) if Activity2 is `singleTask`. You can only get a result back from an Activity that runs in the same task as the Activity that started it. #2 if you haven't specified a different `taskAffinity` for Activity2, it **will not** run in a separate task even if you specify `launchMode="singleTask"`.

Comment: Also, why do you have Activity2 as `singleTask`?